# Chrome on Android 100% height and width more than viewport?

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, mobile

I am having a problem with Chrome on android mobile phones where an element on my webpage that is 100% width and height is going beyond the viewport?

It seems to work no problem on Android Browser, Firefox for Android, Chrome, Firefox and IE on desktop.

Link to my website: https://www.codesmite.com

If you shrink the page to a mobile size you will see the sidebar menu hides away off screen and a menu button appears to bring it back. When you click the menu button the sidebar transitions across to 100% width and height and the content transitions off the screen to the right. I have overflow:hidden so the content should not be stretching it wrapper but instead leaving the viewport, which works.

For some reason on Chrome for Android the 100% height of the element reaches all the way to the bottom of the page (It isn't fixed anymore, if you scroll down the menu items disappear). The width also stretches beyond the viewport width to the edge of all the overflowing content?

I can't work out what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

On your `<div id='content'>` you have
@media only screen and (max-width: 749px), screen and (max-height: 549px)
global.min.css:1#header:target~#content {
    `left: 100%;`

Delete `left: 100%;` and will work;

Or add CSS: `div#content{display:none;}` when you open menu, both works for me.

Comment: Why would that break on Chrome for Mobile and nothing else? Does overflow not work in Chrome for Mobile?

Comment: Overflow just hide your scrollbar, if your page is bigger than the window will hide the scrollbar but the page will still be bigger than your window